# MS Access: Combine columns and rows to unique rows

Tags: crosstab

Currently I have a table which looks like the following:

```
+-----+---------+-----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
| AID |   Name  | TID | 01 | 02 | 03 | .. | 69 | 70 |
+-----+---------+-----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
| 001 | Amy     | 3   |    |    | b  |    | d  |    |
+-----+---------+-----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
| 002 | Bob     | 3   | a  | c  |    |    |    |    |
+-----+---------+-----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
| 003 | Charley | 1   |    |    |    |    |    |    |
+-----+---------+-----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
```

And I'm trying to get it to look like:

```
+-----+------+-----+----------+----------+
| AID | Name | TID | Question | Response |
+-----+------+-----+----------+----------+
| 001 | Amy  | 3   | 03       | b        |
+-----+------+-----+----------+----------+
| 001 | Amy  | 3   | 69       | d        |
+-----+------+-----+----------+----------+
| 002 | Bob  | 3   | 01       | a        |
+-----+------+-----+----------+----------+
| 002 | Bob  | 3   | 02       | c        |
+-----+------+-----+----------+----------+
```

I think I want to do a crosstab query but am struggling wrapping my head around this concept. Also, the name column is irrelevant. I just threw it in there to help connect the dots if needed.

The table was setup in a rush and I'm finally getting around to setting it up properly. It is used to store the incorrect responses to many different tests (TID) and each column is a question number. This is obviously a bad setup if I were to have 71 question tests in the future. I currently have it setup properly but am trying to import the data without manually going through about 300 rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your not trying to create a CrossTab, you're try to take CrossTab data and show it normal. Don't think you can do this with a CrossTab. You can do this with 70 UNION 'ed queries. IE,

```
SELECT AID, Name, TID, 01 FROM MyTable
UNION
SELECT AID, Name, TID, 02 FROM MyTable
...ETC...
```

Comment: Thanks, looks like I'll 'script' the 70 unions in excel and run the query. Thanks.